# Adding a JLabel to a JFrame that is using BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, boxlayout

I am creating a `JFrame` that contains a `JPanel` with a grid of buttons. Everything works fine but I then want to add a `JLabel` above the panel of buttons but the label never appears. It does appear if I don't use `BoxLayout`, though. Any help is appreciated.

The first code part below is my `JFrame` class:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Frame extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Panel panel = new Panel();
    Dimension frameDim = new Dimension(1000, 1000);
    Dimension labelDim = new Dimension(100, 20);
    Box box = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Tic Tac Toe");
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();

    public Frame() {

        pane.add(label);
        pane.setPreferredSize(labelDim);
        pane.setMinimumSize(labelDim);
        add(pane);
        box.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        box.add(panel);     
        box.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        add(box);
        setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
        setSize(frameDim);
        setMinimumSize(frameDim);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The code below is my `JPanel` class with buttons:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    private int i;

    JButton[] button = new JButton[9];
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(3, 3);
    Dimension dim = new Dimension(500, 500);

    public Panel() {

        for (i = 0; i<9; i++) {
            button[i] = new JButton();
            add(button[i]);
        }
        setPreferredSize(dim);
        setMinimumSize(dim);
        setMaximumSize(dim);
        setLayout(layout);
    }   
}
```

The last code part below is the `Main` class:

```
public class RunGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want the text field to stretch the entire way across then it should probably go in a different panel. Perhaps make a "main panel" that holds the "box panel" and the "textfield panel". Give the "main panel" a vertical FlowLayout?

Comment: `Frame.panel` isn't being used anywhere (at least in this example). Nevermind, it's being added to the box. But why?

Comment: I just want to have a label appear above the grid so you are saying to put the button grid in the panel with the text?

Comment: Not quite. I'm suggesting 3 panels. --- **1 Main Panel** that holds the child panels. **2 Child Panels**, 1 for your label, 1 for your boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the BorderLayout when adding your label into Pane into the Frame and remove that box thing as below

```
public Frame()
  {
    //create label and add it to the frame
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Tic Tac Toe");
    label.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
    add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    //create buttonsPanel and add it to the frame 
    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
    buttons.setLayout( new GridLayout(3, 3));
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
      buttons.add(new JButton(""+i));
    }
    add(buttons, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //setup the title, other properties for the frame etc.. 
    setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
    setSize(1000, 1000);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
  }
```

hope this helps better :)

Comment: It seems like it should work but when I try it, the label and grid show up side by side instead of above and under each other.

Comment: I edited the code above to show you a fully working example but of course you just need to put it in whatever classes and extend as you wanna design

Answer (score 4):

```
add(box);
```

This is adding the label direct to the `JFrame`, the content pane of which is laid out using a `BorderLayout`. The default when adding to a component to a border layout without any constraint is the `CENTER`, which can only display a single component. To fix it use:

```
pane.add(box);
```